# How to disable wrap text when converting XML to XLS (using XSL)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xls, word-wrap

I am converting an XML to XLS with XSL.
When I open the XLS file, I see that "Wrap Text" is on. 
[image]

How can I create the XLS with "Wrap Text" off ? I want the XLS to look like this:
[image]

This is the Test.xsl:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="Tickets">
      <HTML>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <table style='text-align:left;border:1; cellpadding:0px; cellspacing:0px'>
            <xsl:call-template name="ticket" />
          </table>
        </body>
      </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="ticket">
        <tr style='color:black;font-weight:bold;font:Calibri;font-size:16'>
          <td >This is a very long long text that currently wrap on its cell</td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML:

```css
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Test.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<Tickets>
  <Ticket>
    <id>111</id>
  </Ticket>
</Tickets>
```

This is the code to convert from XML to XLS using XSL:

```
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\MyTest.xls"))
        {
                String xslt = "C:\\Test.xsl";
                var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
                string sb = xDocument.ToString();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xslt);
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
                settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 1024;
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
                String transformstring = XMLTransform(sb, reader);
                sw.Write(transformstring);
        }

        protected string XMLTransform(String xml, XmlReader stylesheet)
    {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
            TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml) as TextReader;
            XmlReader reader3 = XmlReader.Create(tr, settings);
            XPathNavigator navigator = new XPathDocument(reader3).CreateNavigator();
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
            transform.Load(stylesheet, new XsltSettings(false, true), new XmlUrlResolver());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                transform.Transform((IXPathNavigable)navigator, null, (Stream)stream);
                stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (StreamReader reader4 = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!reader4.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(reader4.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is not the file.  It is your excel default settings.  You have to change the default style : https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-excel-defaults-you-can-customize-to-work-the-way-you-want/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
That's what I thought also, but my excel default setting already has "Wrap text" off (not checked). And, when I create a brand new XLS file, the text are NOT wrapped.

Comment: Try to save your brand new XLS as HTML and see which proprietary attributes Excel includes on the table or table cells, then simply use those attributes in the HTML you create in the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you, Martin !
In the XSL file, to the table attribute, I added style="white-space: nowrap", and that did it ! Thank you !
<table style='text-align:left;border:1; cellpadding:0px; cellspacing:0px;white-space: nowrap'>